# Read RPG bot in discord using Python bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Am trying to make simple python bot to read RPG bot and when there is group event it would send text to call everyone to come. Am using Replit so I would say the latest python 3.8.2

```py
import requests
import discord
import time


client = discord.Client()

async def on_ready():
  print('Logged in As {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
      return

    msg = message.content
     if message.content.startswith('Event'):
      time.sleep(2)
      await message.channel.send("Event Starting @everyone")

     if any(word in msg for word in ('event')):   
      time.sleep(2)
      await message.channel.send("@everyone Event time")


client.run(os.environ['token'])
```

Comment: There are a lot of errors here. Do read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use discord rewrite if you are not use that https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

Small example with using your code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import time
import os
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents.default())

bot.remove_command("help")

token = "token here"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"We have logged in as {bot.user}")

@bot.event
async def on_message(msg):
    await bot.process_commands(msg)
    if msg.author == bot.user or msg.author.bot:
       return
    elif "event" in msg.content.lower(): #here we are lower all message content and try to finding "event" word in message.
        time.sleep(2)
        await msg.channel.send("Event Starting @everyone")
        return

#if you want to use this as bot command, not as default text.
@bot.command(name="event")
async def event(msg):
  time.sleep(2)
  await msg.channel.send("Event Starting @everyone")
  return
            

bot.run(token)
```